# Wrong position of <video> element inside SVG foreignObject on Safari

Tags: html, svg, safari

I'm using `<foreignObject>` SVG element to embed a `<video>` element inside an SVG-based UI.

Everything is fine on all browsers but Safari, where the positioning of the video element is completely wrong respect to its `<foreingObject>` container.

I built a simple page to reproduce the issue, also available on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/sertal70/pen/qBOLdNZ?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=edf67f7539aa2af519989f94b66063f52f99da1e-1589902150-0-AXGuz9U9A1VyJN9RMYrS3O-bE77TWCtDZj8FWjPZ2suMaqzRmobTsSUmajyKdXhpehixtTozxYxSL1Hut0LcWLGTuZVS6hdSYKTS_SKTZLTYi_QE1dmrftTXQWjCobny_CET__5G--MOWBVDH0SaQf_E4WqkRikdE9UZZNg7nqfzwnu-Ds_8Mn9wL_jqf4MGw1p8Qs0PJ9185Q7EjMzdmnuCrgbZqV-jkbt4C0czhWxQddBHyJFPSp3JiNVOuDPDqsB9PvQoiBLvnYD8o7zgRJcKMNtSpV_phP8WIRuDvMq5QNbVmlBkyhB-8u-wz42cfT3xUdy5t46SoJ0_qeofD-hhnC3_GdyS7wu7aWHShVP8):

```html
<body style='background-color: #999'>
  <svg viewBox='0 0 100 200' style='width: 200px; height: 400px; border: 1px solid black'>

    <foreignObject x='10' y='10' width='80' height='80'>
      <div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' style='height: 100%; background-color: white; border: 1px solid blue'>
        <span>bla bla bla</span>
      </div>
    </foreignObject>

    <foreignObject x='10' y='110' width='80' height='80'>
      <div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'  style='width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 1px solid red'>
        <video xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' width='100%' height='100%' playsinline autoplay src='https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4'></video>
      </div>
    </foreignObject>

  </svg>

</body>
```

Here there is the rendered page: on the left Chrome version, on the right the Safari one.

[image]

[caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-svg_elements_foreignobject) states that `<foreignObject>` is supported on Safari and actually the video element is displayed. But what's wrong with its positioning?

Comment: Presumably a bug in safari. Have you checked [its bugtracker](https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs/)

Answer (score 10):

Hard to believe, this is a [bug in webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23113). More hard to believe, this bug is open since ... 2009!!!

Having a look at comments on the bug page, it turns out that a possible workaround is to add `position: fixed` to the style of the `div` containing the `video` element.

Thanks to @Robert Longson for pointing me in the right direction.

Personal comment: I can't understand why caniuse declares `foreignObject` as supported on Safari when this bug is open for such a long time.

Comment: Alas, I've not found a workaround for my layout. Did you find any other tricks that make it work?