# Why is a video in an SVG not scaled properly on Safari?

Tags: html, css, svg, safari, html5-video

I tried to embed a video inside an SVG with a  tag, but the video does not scale correctly.
A workaround where I put the video outside the SVG could work, but this is not an option for me.
It works on Chrome and Firefox but not on Safari. Even though the video tag is (on hover with the selector tool) appropriately scaled, the video itself isn't.

After researching, I tumbled upon similar problems like:
[Wrong position of <video> element inside SVG foreignObject on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61895287/wrong-position-of-video-element-inside-svg-foreignobject-on-safari) and
[SVG foreignObject not working properly on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51313873/svg-foreignobject-not-working-properly-on-safari)

This "fixed" the problem with the positioning but not the scale one.

So I tried to isolate the problem as much as possible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body,html{
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 3840 2160">
        <foreignObject width='3840' height='2160'>
            <video width='3840' height='2160' muted playsinline autoplay >
                <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
            </video>
        </foreignObject>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

It is basically now only an SVG and a video. But this is what it looks like on Safari v16.0:
[Video on Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmQHi.jpg) and [on Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB2Qy.jpg)

I thought this was the way to fix this issue, but now I don't know what to do.
Maybe someone else can find a workaround for this bug.

Comment: Have you tried setting the height and width to `100%` instead?

Comment: Why? Presumably a bug. Feel free to [report it](https://bugs.webkit.org/) to webkit's bugtracker.

Comment: @r3mainer  Yes I tried this and it did not work.
I tried different styling options as well, like using absolute instead of relative width and height, and position: absolute.

Answer (score 2):

After playing around a little more, I found a workaround for Safari. If you add `width: 100vw;` and `height: 100vh;` to the video tag, the video itself now [does what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaHPt.png), even though the suggested position and scale are still off. Sadly, [Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0Gck.png) holds the suggested scale. Nothing that can't be solved with browser detection. This workaround probably only works in my case and is not a general solution, but maybe it helps someone else.